# TFP401 LCD flickering with Rasp Pi

Tags: gpio

We have bought two modules Rasp Pi 3 module and TFP401 module (with touch screen).
While driving PWM signal <1KHz, we are seeing flicker on LCD.
If PWM signal source is external, no flickering on LCD.
Can you please provide the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you mean by 'best' solution.
You should add more detail on what you intend to achieve.

If you are looking for more information on controlling the backlight brightness, see [this](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-tfp401-hdmi-slash-dvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-display.pdf) tutorial, 
it would appear a pwm signal of >= 1 kHz is  recommended (page 12 of 21). Quoted here incase the link expires

> If you want to adjust the backlight brightness, you can feed a PWM signal (1KHz or greater) into the Backlight pin, 3-5V logic level. Or you can just connect it to ground to turn off the backlight driver. This will greatly reduce the power usage

I am not sure why an external source (< 1 kHz) would appear to work without flicker though as it shouldnt matter where the pulses come from.

If you are looking to programatically control the PWM duty cycle, and are comfortable working with C or Python consider using the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library.

There are also number of [examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html) to get you started.